# Webpack: concatenate file as part of output?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: './js/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: './js/main.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
    ]
};
```

I'd like to amend it so that I concatenate a file called `./js/vendor/foo.js` to the top of the output file (above the content of `index.js`).

Is this possible with webpack?

Comment: Can’t you just import/require vendor.js at the top of index.js?

Comment: I have the same question: what I want to put on top of the output file is a comment that contains info about the file. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

webpack creates a bundle file, that is all controlled by modules. If you need to load something BEFORE webpack loads just put a script tag for that in your HTML and put that above the webpack bundle.js. But if you are trying to control the ordering of specific content inside the bundle that webpack creates than that would be a bad idea really. The point of webpack is that it's gonna control ordering itself, so you don't have to worry about it. (actually it's module loading, not 'ordering' in this case)